# What are the mechanical deflection angles for Airbus side-stick controllers?

Tags: flight-controls, airbus, sidestick

Does anyone know the angular deflection limits of the longitudinal (pitch) and lateral (roll) axis of Airbus's side-stick?

Answer (score 2):

From [this site](http://www.kls2.com/cgi-bin/arcfetch?db=sci.aeronautics.airliners&id=%3Cairliners.1992.154@ohare.chicago.com%3E):

[image]

So max deflection in pitch is +/- 16 deg, in roll it is +/- 20 deg

Answer (score -1):

There is a rather quick YouTube video by a gentleman called Capt. Joe which can partially answer your question.

The limits of the effective deflection of the sidestick is presented on the PFD, which that also changes with many variable factors to allow the aircraft to operate within its approved and safe performance envelope.

Comment: What's presented on the PFD is elevator & aileron deflection, not sidestick deflection.

Comment: And anyway the answer should be in the text, not in the linked video only (or it should be a comment).

Comment: I tried to put in the link in my comment, but unfortunately the whole  YouTube piece popped up as my answer. Sorry for disturbing you, I beg your forgiveness.